# XSL - replace all instances of a tag with another recursively

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML looking like this:

```
<Viewbox Width="29.513" Height="57.478"
  >
  <Canvas>
    <Canvas>
    <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Group>/<Compound Path> -->
    <Path Fill="#ffffffff" Data="F1... Z"/>
    <Path StrokeThickness="0.9" Stroke="#ff59595b" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Data="F1 ...698"/>
  </Canvas>
  </Canvas>


</Viewbox>
```

My XSL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <DrawImage>
      <xsl:for-each select="//Canvas">
        <DrawingGroup><xsl:copy-of select="child::*" /></DrawingGroup>
    </xsl:for-each>   
      <xsl:for-each select="//Path">
      <GeometryDrawing>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@Fill">        
        <xsl:attribute name="Brush">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Fill"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="@Stroke">        
        <xsl:attribute name="Brush">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Stroke"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:attribute name="Geometry">
          <xsl:value-of select="@Data"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(string-length(@StrokeThickness)&lt;1 or string-length(@StrokeStartLineCap)&lt;1  or string-length(@StrokeEndLineCap)&lt;1  or string-length(@StrokeLineJoin)&lt;1)">    
        <Pen>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@StrokeThickness">           
          <xsl:attribute name="Thickness">
            <xsl:value-of select="@StrokeThickness"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>      
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@StrokeStartLineCap">  
      <xsl:attribute name="StartLineCap">
            <xsl:value-of select="@StrokeStartLineCap"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
                 </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@StrokeEndLineCap">  
      <xsl:attribute name="EndLineCap">
            <xsl:value-of select="@StrokeEndLineCap"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@StrokeLineJoin">  
      <xsl:attribute name="LineJoin">
            <xsl:value-of select="@StrokeLineJoin"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
        </Pen>
       </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>      
      </GeometryDrawing>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </DrawImage>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Something isn't right. My output was *supposed* to look like shown below, but instead I get the Geometrydrawings outside DrawingGroup and DrawingGroup is not nested like Canvas was.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DrawImage>
  <DrawingGroup>
  <DrawingGroup>
  <GeometryDrawing Brush="#ffffffff" Geometry="F1....478 Z" />
  <GeometryDrawing Brush="#ff59595b" Geometry="F1...98">
    <Pen Thickness="0.9" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" />
  </GeometryDrawing>
  </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingGroup>
</DrawImage>
```

I hope someone can tell me what to put inside my DrawingGroup element in my xsl

Comment: The Path->GeometryDrawing transform works fine - it is just the Canvas->DrawingGroup that fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use templates e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Canvas">
  <DrawingGroup>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </DrawingGroup>
</xsl:template>
```

then you can easily write modular code that transforms each element as needed, preserving the original document structure.

You simply need to add more templates like

```
<xsl:template match="@Fill">
  <xsl:attribute name="Brush" select="."/><!-- XSLT 2.0 -->
  <!-- or XSLT 1.0 <xsl:attribute name="Brush"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>-->
</xsl:template>
```

No need for `for-each` and `choose/when`.

If there are element or attributes you want to delete then use e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo"/>` to delete the complete element or `<xsl:template match="foo"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` to process only its child nodes respectively `<xsl:template match="@bar"/>` to not process `bar` attributes.

Comment: I tried to have an extra template like the one you decribed, but that just removes the Canvas/DrawingGroup tags entirely...
Or should I then change<xsl:template match="/" > and  <xsl:for-each select="//Path"> to a template match on Path?

Comment: Ah....tried that....and it appears to work
I now have:
<xsl:template match="Viewbox" priority="-2">
  <DrawImage>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </DrawImage>
</xsl:template>
  
    
  <xsl:template match="Canvas" priority="-2">
  <DrawingGroup>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </DrawingGroup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Path" >
 <GeometryDrawing>
....

That seemed to work!

Thanks for your time

Comment: My suggestion is meant to change the whole approach to use template matching and apply-templates, that way the document structure is preserved. So you would not need the template you have shown, instead start with e.g. `<xsl:template match="Viewbox"><DrawImage><xsl:apply-templates/></DrawImage></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Tried that, and that also seemed to work fine. Strangely, though, the GeometryDrawing and Pen is now on the same line even though I have <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>